# How to determine which compiler has been used to compile an executable?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction

From a compiled file, can I see which compiler has been used to generate the file?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/80605/detect-compiler-used-for-exe-file

Comment: What do you mean by a compiled file? An object file or an executable?

Comment: @John Bartholomew: care to put this up as an answer?

Comment: @Christian: Done. I've seen duplicate notices typically posted as comments -- not sure what the convention is when it's a cross-site duplicate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's also the good old 'strings' utility. Dumps all ascii-ish looking strings it finds in the binary. Different compilers embed different amounts of information in the binaries they produce, but many will actually include obviously identifying strings.

Comment: sometimes you can directly get the compiler name and even version number this way, w/the caveat that you need to wade through a lot of other stuff. even if the compiler isn't kind enough to ID itself, you could possibly learn to recognize the strings in the run-time. grep the output from strings for things like gcc to speed things along.

Answer (score 5):

Many compilers/linkers insert a `.comment` section in the output file which identifies them. There are also a number of more subtle behaviors you could create compiler fingerprints off of, but I know of no existing tools for this.

If you have the source, the easiest solution would be to try compiling with each compiler in question until you get a binary that matches byte-for-byte (or even closely).

Comment: And `.note.*` sections are added.

Answer (score 4):

In some cases you can run `ldd` on the binary and find out which standard library it's linked against. For example on Solaris gcc vs Sun CC vs whatever.

For C++ code, you can also dump some of the symbols, find a mangled function name, and then figure out which demangler generates the correct original name.

Comment: Name mangling is not enough to differentiate it, icc will just mangle it like gcc for example.

Answer (score 3):

Try, [IDA Pro](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/idadownfreeware.htm) which identifies the libraries and tools used to build up executable file.

Answer (score 0):

I was answering a quiz in a Blue Team website, and this was a question. I found the solution using a tool called `PE Detective`, he looks for signatures on the EXE, works really fine

https://www.softpedia.com/get/System/File-Management/PE-Detective.shtml